# Field with @Autowired annotation in a class with @Component annotation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

A field with @Autowired annotation

- it works if the field is in a class with the annotation @Controller
- but it does not work if the field is in a class with the annotation @Component

¿Can someone tell me how should I put a field with the @Autowired annotation in a class that has the @Component annotation?

Thanks and regards

In the class Modelo1Controller

```
@Controller
public class Modelo1Controller {    

    @Autowired  
    private SelectUtil selectUtil;
```

the selectUtil field has value and works correctly

But in the class Modelo

```
@Component
public class Modelo extends BeanCommon implements Serializable {

    @Autowired  
    private SelectUtil selectUtil;
```

When I try to use the selectUtil field the value is null and I get NullPointerException

String text = selectUtil.getDescripcionBienText(value);

java.lang.NullPointerException: null

And the class SelectUtil

```
@Component
public class SelectUtil {
```

Comment: That should not happen. Could you show some code and add more details, refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you look at `@Controller` annotation implementation, it is also annotated with `@Component` so if you annotate your class with `@Controller` it is also a component. There has to be something wrong with your code, so share it with us so we can help.

Comment: No, that should work, please provide more code.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have made my application work

The main problem was that I used the new operator to instantiate the object in another code block

Every day I'm learning new Spring concepts

In any case, thanks and maybe the problem and the solution can be used by more people in the same situation